# Using Gradle to generate jax-ws java sources

Tags: ant, websphere, gradle

I have a wsdl and I'd like to generate jax-ws type Java source from it using IBM Websphere version of wsimport. How can I do this in an easy way? wsimport.bat references  com.ibm.ws.jaxws.tools.WsImport to do the code generation.

Comment: Which version of WebSphere? Do you have WebSphere development tools, or just the WebSphere runtime?

Comment: both. And it should be com.ibm.ws.jaxws.tools.WsImport not WsGen btw. I'll make the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling wsimport directly. Just make sure websphereHome is set to the websphere home folder on your machine. Then genDir is the folder where you want the files to be generated to. Finally, wsdlFile is the path to the wsdl used for generation.

```
task generateWSDL2Java(type:Exec) { 

    doFirst{
        genDir.mkdirs()
    }
    cmd = websphereHome + '/bin/wsimport.bat -keep -d  '+genDir+' '+wsdlFile    
    commandLine = ['cmd', '/K', cmd]    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Ant script, using a WebSphere 6.1 runtime (with the WebSphere Feature Pack, which is required for JAX-WS), which I just tested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="JAX-WS Client">
    <property name="was.dir" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer"/>

    <path id="jaxws.gen.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${was.dir}/plugins">
            <include name="*com.ibm.wsfp.main_6.1.0.jar" />
            <include name="*org.apache.axis2_6.1.0.jar" />
            <include name="*com.ibm.jaxws.tools_6.1.0.jar" />
            <include name="*com.ibm.jaxb.tools_6.1.0.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset file="${was.dir}/lib/j2ee.jar"/>
    </path>

    <!-- Ant task definition for wsimport -->
    <taskdef classpathref="jaxws.gen.classpath" name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport"/>

    <target name="wsimport">
        <wsimport sourcedestdir="./src" destdir="./build" debug="true" verbose="true"
                  keep="true" wsdl="${wsdlFile}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

If you have RAD 8, here's [the InfoCenter article which describes using the JAX-WS Ant tasks](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.webservice.doc/topics/jaxws/tantclientjaxws.html) from within that. I'm not sure how other WebSphere development environments compare.

Comment: I'm using RAD8/WAS8 right now, so I'll check out the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-WS artifacts are portable, which means that you are not required to use IBM's tools. BTW, I think that the wsgen and wsimport tools shipped with WAS actually use code from the Sun/Oracle reference implementation.

Therefore you could use any documented solution for Gradle, even if it is not WebSphere specific.